# how to make a div appear below the other in css

Tags: css, html

```
<div id="header">
 <>.....<>
  <div id="Menu" style="background-color: #662900; font-size: 20px; height: auto; width: 100%; word-spacing: 50px; position: absolute; float: left">
```

I want the div id-menu to be displayed right below the header div.

Comment: Do you mean there shouldn't be any space between the header and your div?

Comment: Would you can **graphically represent** what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Is your menu div inside your header div?

Comment: To be able to help you better it would be good if you answered questions in the comments. Also it would be easier if you described your question better and give an example what is not working and how you would like it to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style media="all">
#header {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
    Header</div>
  <div id="Menu" style="background-color: #662900; font-size: 20px; height: auto; width: 100%; word-spacing: 50px; position: absolute; float: left"> Menu
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/b5UrP/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

you can add `margin: 0` in your css to appear right below.
In your code you forgot to close header div, so the div menu is inside the header div

Answer (score 0):

see this  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ksgRZ/) .

Since you have `absolute` menu, my suggestion would be to go with `relative` header.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="header">
     <>.....<>
    <div id="Menu" style=""> 
          Menu 
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header{position:relative}
#Menu{background-color: #662900; font-size: 20px; height: auto; width: 100%; word-spacing: 50px; position: absolute; float: left}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu{
position: absolute;
right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you giving position absolute to your menu div, you need to specify that position with

```
top: _enter here your header height
left:0px;
```